# My 15-year-old daughter is having sex with her boyfriend who is a drug dealer

Tags: teen, relationships, sex, drugs, sexual-consent

My daughter is 15 and her boyfriend is 17. They are having sex and I'm not sure if I want her to.

On top of that, her boyfriend is a drug dealer, but she thinks that he is cool because he makes a lot of money off it.

Is there anything I can do? Help.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE :) Another Q&A that may have some useful information (generally applicable, about talking to teenage children about sexual activity): [What should we do when our 15 year old wants sex with his 13 year old girlfriend?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18694/what-should-we-do-when-our-15-year-old-wants-sex-with-his-13-year-old-girlfriend)

Comment: Make her watch you browse internet for "drug abusers". Some lively pictures may show her that what he's doing is ... evil?

Comment: What country are you in? Here in the UK, your daughter would be [under the age of consent](http://www.fpa.org.uk/factsheets/law-on-sex) and her boyfriend over the age of consent, so there would be a potential legal issue (for the boyfriend).

Comment: If you're in the USA we also need to know your state. Some states have wildly different consent laws.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning to her that, as an adult, trying to be a bad boy looks totally pathetic. Maybe ask her if she sees herself tagging along in his exciting life in her 20s, when the few hundred bucks you can make dealing bad weed to your friends looks more like failure and less like the high life. Also, where are his parents?

Comment: I'm a little bit of a psycho so maybe my approach might not be what you're looking for. What if you show an interest in him? Isn't it typical of teenagers to like guys their parents don't approve of? What if you were always inviting him over, asking her about him, telling her how much you like him, etc? I had a friend get very upset once because her mom approved of me too much. She showed so much of an interest that her daughter pretty much vanished from my life. She gave me a bag of her daughter's hair! Reverse psychology and an instant turn off. If it backfires... worst idea ever.

Comment: I definitely agree with Erik. The Question here is not "my daughter is having sex" but "my daughter has a relationship with a drug dealer".

Comment: @Egg Couldn't this backfire though? People often over-estimate their likelihood of "making it big", and drug dealing is no exception. For every few hundred small-time drug mules that makes a couple hundred here and there, there's a bigger distributor raking in wads of cash, and so on up the chain. Just like in every other "career" path, people tend to think that one day, that could be them.

Comment: If you know he's a drug dealer, simply notify the police. They'll take care of the problem for you.

Comment: @Omegacron That is fairly unlikely. The problem the police have with catching and punishing drug dealers is rarely the fact that they don't know WHO they are.

Comment: @DRF - agreed, the problem is usually catching them. I speak from experience, though - my daughter dated a guy at 16 who had a warrant for possession. Once we found out, we called the police and told them where they could find the guy. They picked him up two days later and shipped him off to whatever state the warrant was for. Problem solved.

Comment: She's going to have sex (regardless of whether this relationship continues or not, there will be others, both good and bad). Teach her the importance of safe and protected sex, at least. In my opinion the *worst* thing you can do, long term, is create an environment where she consistently hides things from you or feels ashamed of her actions / relationships in general, because then, communication breaks down entirely. (And also, though, drug dealer, yeah, you should find a way to do something about that. But this comment is just about the sex part!)

Comment: Google for "why do drug dealers still live with their moms" and show her the results. Not only is the money pathetic to any adult, but it's a dangerous job (there's a claim that death risk of drug dealers in some places is higher than death risk of convicted criminals on death row in Texas).

Comment: @JasonC  There is no such thing as safe sex with a child.  Sex with a child is abhorrent and should be immediately stopped and dealt with.

Comment: @Physics-Compute On one hand, there's your beliefs and a feeling that you can control all things, but on the other hand, there's reality and actually dealing with it. You decide. Unless you want to risk becoming an early grandparent.

Answer (score 24):

There isn't much you can do to *force* a change in their relationship. You can establish curfews, household rules, and so on, but unless you plan to watch her every minute of every day, she'll find a way to break a rule that you put in place. While she is certainly not an adult yet, your daughter's old enough to make some decisions on her own.

The best way to end this relationship is to get her to end it, and have her look at it in a realistic, mature way. Emphasize the reasons that you are worried, and get her to really think about these issues.

It may be necessary to get a different adult involved in the conversation — a godparent, a favorite aunt, a school counselor somebody. The knee-jerk reaction of teens is "you don't understand me" and she may be less dismissive if these hard, important questions are brought up by somebody else.

**Safe Sex.** Is he wearing a condom every single time, *regardless* of whether she's taking an oral birth control? Sexually transmitted disease is a big risk in addition to pregnancy. And **pregnancy** can happen even when multiple forms of contraception are in place. Is she ready to raise a baby? Is she ready to have to face the choice of abortion or teen motherhood? Does she have money saved up in preparation for either option? Is her boyfriend going to be a good parent to their child financially and emotionally for the next eighteen years? Where are they going to live? What will her educational and career path be like when the complication of parenthood is introduced?

**Legal consequences for him.** Depending on the age of consent where you live, their relationship may qualify as statutory rape. Is he so committed to their relationship that he wants to run that risk? Is he interested in hanging out with her in non-sexual contexts until she's older? (While these are sort of questions "for him," ask her to think about them, think about what she'd want his responses to be, think about what his actual responses would be...)

**Legal consequences for her.** Dating a drug dealer isn't just a matter of having a rich, bad-boy boyfriend. Has he ever asked her to carry anything related to his business (drugs, customer money, paraphernalia like rolling paper or empty baggies)? Does he have any of those items in his car when she's riding in it? Even if it's just as innocent as "being in the car" there's a chance she'll be caught up in any subsequent criminal charges (and if she's got anything on her person, it's a *much* bigger deal). Legal trouble — fines, community service, jail time, a criminal record that could potentially follow her throughout college and job applications — creates many short- and long-term repercussions.

Will he nobly take all the blame for drugs and any associated paraphernalia? (The criminal justice system may not care.) Will he put all the blame on her and say he has no idea where the stuff came from? Will he just not bother saying anything? Will he pay for her legal representation as well as his?

**General safety and ethics.** In the course of his "job" he likely deals with a fair amount of dangerous people. If he's in a dispute with somebody, does she want to be around if things get violent? Even if she isn't around for those (hopefully rare) events, does she understand he's profiting from other people's addiction and sickness?

Comment: You're missing the "he'll throw her under the bus and make her his patsy" downside angle...

Comment: Good thought. Brought that in.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP always had the age in the title, but now that we know she's 15 and a legal child, you can improve this answer by removing the notion of tolerating any sex. (If someone knows and is does nothing, they are complicit to the crime).  The answer already does a good job of explaining the consequences she's not ready for.

Comment: The question had the age in the title. And there is nothing in my answer which proposes just standing by and doing nothing, or "tolerating" the sexual relationship.

Answer (score 9):

> she thinks that he is cool because he makes a lot of money off it

Most likely, he's spinning yarns about the money in drug dealing and she's falling for it because she watches too much TV. Studies indicate that low-level drug dealers make $20k-$30k per year. While that's a lot for a 17-year-old, it is not very much money at all by adult standards; pretty much anyone who goes to college is going to make more, let alone students bright enough for the STEM track. Income-wise, her boyfriend is just a notch above minimum wage, and has a high chance of being busted.

The specific suggestion here is to leave aside matters of morality regarding dating a drug dealer and/or being in a relationship primarily for the money and simply emphasize the fact that there isn't that much money in drug dealing, at least for low-level dealers.

Comment: This is borderline OT. There is much more to this question, and this makes no attempt to answer the OP's actual question. Can you please edit your answer to flesh out the moral aspect, or some other advice to help the OP? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Is there anything you can do?  Not really.  I'd say talk to your daughter and make it clear that you know what she's doing, you're not happy about it then go onto making sure she stays protected while having sex.

It's probable this will just end in time and then you'll be there to console your daughter however, you could talk to her and suggest that she turns him down once or twice.  Then she'll see what is the likely real reason he's with her.

Don't ban her from seeing him.  He'll become forbidden fruit and just start seeing him behind your back instead.

If you're absolutely sure that you want to end the relationship (something I wouldn't recommend because she'll blame you) and don't think your daughter will listen then you could, as a last resort only (and this is if you have proof that he is either a) a drug dealer or b) having sex with your underage daughter), call the authorities.

Comment: pretty sure you could anonymously call the authorities too.

Answer (score -3):

Your daughter's sex life is her domain.  That said, I can certainly understand that her choice in this case makes you feel queasy.

You can set up some boundaries, for example, no sex in my house, daughter must come home by such-and-so time or call to let me know where she is and what is the delay, so you won't worry.

You can take her to Planned Parenthood, for contraception and information about safe sex.

You can offer the young man your mentorship in finding a legitimate job, or help him find a helpful mentor.

If he is arrested and convicted, you can go to his sentencing hearing and testify in favor of probation, if you think that sending him to jail at this point would be counterproductive.

You can help your daughter get involved in constructive extracurricular activities she enjoys, where she will hopefully meet a variety of people who are on the up and up, that she will enjoy spending time with.  But please don't tell her your motivation in offering to sign her up for a pottery class or a theater program!

---

I believe the ethical thing to do about the drug dealing is to report his illegal activities to the police.  This need not be done in a theatrical way or with any fanfare.

In a community ravaged by drug use, and all the violence and social problems that come with it, we all share the responsibility of enforcing the laws that are supposed to protect us and our children.

I would suggest that when you go to the police station to make your report, you leave out the part about the sexual relationship.  The officer taking the report will probably suspect that anyway, as your motivation for bringing the drug dealing to their attention, but it is not directly relevant to the work the police need to do about the drug dealing.

I would also suggest that you tell the police that you would like to be a confidential informant.

---

You are doing the right thing by asking yourself these questions.  You have put so much love and energy into raising your daughter.  By consorting with a drug dealer, she is putting herself at risk of arrest, and is raising her risk of developing drug problems.

Comment: Why the down votes, please?

Comment: The "report him to police" is probably the most dangerous part. Drug dealing is done in groups, and it's not hard to track down who did it. If they know who did it, the father is in big trouble.

Comment: @Bradman175 - I don't understand what you're saying.  Do you agree with my suggestion to report the illegal activities to the police?  Are you saying that my advice to make a police report is dangerous?

Comment: A police report can be dangerous. I'm not so sure if you can make your information confidential that easily. My guess though.

Comment: @Bradman175 - Is there a great deal of police corruption where you live?

Comment: Not at all. But America has quite a lot.

Comment: @Bradman175 - What is your source?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_corruption#United_States You realise that I'm trying to make a guess.

Comment: @Bradman175 - Sorry, not convinced.  The source you provided does not seem directly related.

Comment: Please use [chat] for extended discussions.

Comment: -1 for recommending to willfully and irreparably ruin someone's life.

Answer (score -5):

You could tell her that she thinks her boyfriend is cool, but he really is not because he ruins lives. That **might** stop her. You could additionally forbid her to see him, but I'm not sure that will stop her. 
Basically go over to your daughter and tell her that he boyfriend is a bad person.  Or go over to him and say:

> You're a mean person

Comment: I do not think either of these actions will be productive. Telling people how to think almost never works

Comment: He ruins lives? Where was that mentioned?

Comment: @forest he’s a drug dealer, so yeah he ruins lives.

Comment: @TolgaOzses That's... not a very reasonable assumption. There's a big difference between selling heroin to addicted junkies or trying to introduce addictive substances to vulnerable users, and selling weed.